# Some home devices won't connect to the Internet unless the router is restarted

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, ios

I've been using the [CBN CH7466CE router](http://www.icbn.com.tw/portfolio-item/ch7466ce/) provided by Vodafone for more than 2 years now. The router normally serves 2 phones (iOS and Android), 3 laptops (2x macOS, 1x Windows), and a smart-tv. Since I got the router, there were no problems with connection whatsoever.

Now, for the past several weeks I'm having problems connecting to the WIFI on the iOS phone and the 2 macOS laptops, and rarely on the smart-tv. Specifics:

- The problem occurs after a long inactivity, e.g. the laptop or the
  phone is shut down or not used overnight - and then tries to connect with the home WIFI.
- Sometimes, it's enough to deactivate and activate the WIFI connection
  on the phone or laptop, but...
- ...Usually, the only thing that helps is restarting the router itself. Often, I can see that I'm connected to the network, but there's no internet access.
- After the router restart, the devices have no problem reinitializing the
  connection, as if the lack of Internet access happened only once each time and then "clicked"
  back into place.

The Android phone and the Windows laptop do not seem to have a problem with connecting to the Internet at all.

**Where do I start to look for the issue?**

Comment: Look in the router using a browser to see if there was a recent firmware upgrade, post back if there was. If you cannot access the router then you should contact Vodaphone for tech support.

Comment: Is it possible that these devices have exhausted their DHCP leases and have difficulties renewing them?

Comment: @Moab I'd love to do that, but logging in into the router GUI ends up with this error showing up each time: *Web GUI support a single session only*. No clue how to get around this at this point, so I guess I'll wait a few hours (?) for the existing user session to expire...

Comment: @harrymc I suppose this is possible. Question why does this problem suddenty occur and what would be the workaround here? Obviously, restarting the router every day is suboptimal.

Comment: Try to factory reset the router (some settings may be lost). Check also for a firmware update (impossible to locate on the ICBN site).

Comment: @harrymc Alright, I did the factory reset yesterday and today the devices I mentioned in the post had no problems connecting to the Internet. Interesting. BTW, the lease time on the DHCP is set to 168h by default. So far so good.

Comment: I added an answer to that effect. If the problem seems to be gone, you might accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some setting of the router might have changed, perhaps after an automatic
firmware update or even just because of some glitch.

Try to factory reset the router to return to a known state.
Some settings may be lost and will have to be reset.

Comment: The factory reset helped, indeed. Kinda disappointing, though, because I hoped for something more challenging ;) Thanks.